# browser not sending cookie back to php?

Tags: php, cookies

i have a php script that uses setcookie to set a cookie called "sess". i am using secure=true method with "" as the domain.

in both FF and safari, i can see the cookie is set for the same domain as the __ut (google analytics) cookies

but when i load a page and print_r($_COOKIE) i get only the __ut cookies, and not the "sess" cookie

why isn't php seeing the cookie? is the browser even sending it?

Comment: Please paste some code into your question so we can see what you are doing...

Comment: (Sideline) Option `secure=true` works only if you use secure connection, otherwise, [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) is not sending any data to the client.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using secure mode, make sure you're also using a valid https connection. Also, you should probably specify the domain instead of a blank string.

Does that help?

Comment: +1 - domain parameter in setcookie() can be empty string on HTTPS (I use domain="" on my server with HTTPS and it works).

Comment: i read somewhere that if i use the domain, secure.domain.com, the browser would automatically add a ".". and it looks like that was true, when i used "", the cooke was set to secure.domain.com and when i used "secure.domain.com", the cookie was set at ".secure.domain.com" - is there another way to get rid of that extra dot?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't checking $_COOKIE from the same request in which you are trying to set the cookie. Cookies aren't available until after the request in which they are set is complete.

Comment: this is not an answer. you should put it in the comment.

Comment: It's an answer if he's checking it from the same request where he's setting it... Will rephrase.